# What is it called when you chain verb phrases together?

Tags: grammar

What is it called in the following sentence?
"We'll show you pictures of it, tell you stories about it."

Comment: Omission of the conjunction (in this case *and*) is a rhetorical device called *asyndeton*. Your grammarians may consider it incorrect, so be sure to avoid them.

Comment: It's fine if you're Julius Caesar, but he had a big army. (And spoke Latin.)

Answer (score 1):

This sentence,

> "We'll show you pictures of it, tell you stories about it."

strings together a complete sentence,

> "We'll show you pictures of it"

with a sentence fragment,

> "tell you stories about it"

The two parts need to be connected by a conjunction such as "and" or "or" in order to be grammatically correct.

The way it is written now could be described as **"a run-on sentence"**.

Comment: As @Tinfoil Hat cleverly commented, the omission or absence of a conjunction between parts of a sentence can be used as a literary (or rhetorical?) device, the term for which is asyndeta (or asyndeton?) The fragments are semantically connected but do not constitute a grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the word "[diazeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis#Diazeugma)":
"A diazeugma is a zeugma whose only subject governs multiple verbs."

An example is given:
"We shall pay any price, bear any burden, meet any hardship, support any friend, oppose any foe to assure the survival and the success of liberty." (Inaugural address of John F. Kennedy)